# iOS 7 CIFeature: CIDetectorEyeBlink doesnt detect closed eyes in image

Tags: iphone, ios7, core-image

Im working on an iPhone app where Im trying to implement CIDetectorEyeBlink to check if the person in the image has closed eyes. But the leftEyeClosed and rightEyeClosed properties always return 0/NO.

I pasted some of the my code for implementation.

```
 CIImage* image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:originalImage.CGImage];

CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                                          context:nil options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]];

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], CIDetectorEyeBlink, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], CIDetectorSmile, nil];

NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:image options:options];

for(CIFaceFeature* faceObject in features)
{
    NSLog(@"TEST left eyeblink: %@", faceObject.leftEyeClosed ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    NSLog(@"TEST right eyeblink: %@", faceObject.rightEyeClosed ? @"YES" : @"NO");
}
```

Comment: On which device are you testing these ? This feature might not be available on some devices

Comment: Im testing on an iPhone 4S running ios 7

Comment: Did you double check that the CIImage you're taking from the originalImage isn't nil?
Depending on how you create this original UIImage, this is possible.

Comment: Well the CIImage isn't nil. The smile detection works well. It is just the leftEyeClosed / rightEyeClosed detection that doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was having the same issue but after trying out this [tutorial](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2013/10/14/quick-tip-detecting-smiles-using-ios-7-objective-c.aspx) I realized that I was not adding the: [CIDetectorImageOrientation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIDetector_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/CIDetectorImageOrientation) option for example:

```
NSDictionary *detectorOptions = @{ CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh };
    CIDetector *faceDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:detectorOptions];

    NSArray *features = [faceDetector featuresInImage:[CIImage imageWithCGImage:_imageView.image.CGImage]
                                              options:@{ CIDetectorSmile : @YES,
                                                         CIDetectorEyeBlink : @YES,
                                                         CIDetectorImageOrientation :[NSNumber numberWithInt:ORIENTATION_NUMBER] }];
```

Now it works smooth ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code. The blink detector will succeed on some images and fail on others, rather inconsistently. Try for yourself on several images.